# Easily Open Existing Non-Eclipse Project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide

Alright, this has caused me enough grief. The answer may be dead simple, but I need some help.

I figured it would be simple to open an existing project in Eclipse, but I'm having quite a time actually making this work.  I don't want to change where it's located.  I don't want to pull a bunch of strings to get Eclipse to point to it.  I just want to take the project directory from where it is now and open it in Eclipse.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure that I entirely follow, but here's my general routine for creating projects in Eclipse.

1. I go to `File > New > Project` and
   pick out what sort of project I
   want, and hit `Next`.
2. I enter the name I want to use for
   the project, and the path where I
   want to store it.  I never store
   stuff in my workspace folder.
3. For projects with existing code, I
   just put the path to the existing
   folder, and Eclipse just imports the
   code.

Hoping that answers your question, but if not let me know.

Comment: That's how I deal with projects stored in Perforce.   It's much easier leaving them where P4V wants to put them, and let Eclipse use them in place.   (And to be picky, Eclipse doesn't import them, as noted above, it just uses them where they are.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And thanks to @muffinista for the great answer.